# Representation of a polynomial in the Chebyshev form

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, approximation-theory

Show that every $ p\in P_n $ has a unique representation in the form 
$ p\left(x\right)=A_0+A_1T_1\left(x\right)+...+A_nT_n\left(x\right) $ 
where $ T_i $ are Chebyshev polynomials.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

is this true for this question?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fsi1O.png

Comment: Welcome to MSE. In order to get responses that suit your needs, please include in the body of the question (not in comments) your own thoughts, the effort made so far, and the specific difficulties that got you stuck.

Comment: You need to match coefficients from $n$th order to $0$th in sequence.

Comment: I know $\left\{T_i\right\}=\left\{1,cos\theta,cos2\theta,...,cosn\theta\right\}$
And for example $p\left(x\right)=a_0+a_1x+...+a_nx^n$
How do I relate these?

Comment: The Chebyshev polynomials are polynomials. You don't need to work out the coefficients, but you do need to know that $T_{n}$ has degree $n$.